# Why is WP_Query not displaying expected data?

Tags: wp-query, custom-field

I have a website where posts expire. Currently I do this manually but I would prefer todo this automatically. I have been struggling with this for a few months now and I thought I finally found the solution with wp_query() but it is not displaying the expected results, instead it is displaying the last 10 posts that were published.

This is the current code:

```
function expire_posts() {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $getdate = get_post_meta($post_id, 'Expiry Date', true);
    $expirydate = date ('d F Y', strtotime ($getdate));
    $today = date( 'd F Y');
    $args = array (strtotime($expirydate) < strtotime($today));
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
?><ol><?php
    if( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query- 
>the_post(); 
?>
        <li><?php the_title(); ?></li><?php
    endwhile; 
?></ol><?php
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
```

I have also used the following code and it returned the same results:

```
function expire_posts() {
    $args = array(
    'meta_key'     => 'Expiry Date',
'meta_value'   => date( "d F Y" ), // change to how "event date" is stored
'meta_compare' => '<',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?><ol><?php
    if( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query- 
>the_post(); 
?>
        <li><?php the_title(); ?></li><?php
    endwhile; 
?></ol><?php
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
```

It should return two specific published posts where the expiry date has past.

Comment: And what does it mean that the post is expired? What should happen in such case? They shouldn't be displayed on site?

Comment: The aim is to update the post status to expired so that it doesn't show up in the search. Before I get to this step I first want to make sure that it is returning the correct data.

Comment: OK, so if you really need to change its status, then you should use WP Cron to do it automatically. But... If the only aim is to stop them to show, then using pre_get_posts will be much easier way... Last question: What is the format of date in Expiry Date field?

Comment: 'd F Y' so '01 June 2018'. It is to update the post_status and post_modified

Comment: OK, so there is no way to compare it using WP_Query. Can you change that format to `YYYY-mm-dd` or `YYYYmmdd`?

Comment: Funny enough, while I was doing reseach I came across that, but with futher reseach I saw that you could store the date however you wanted to. That second fuction with the meta-query came out of the codex. I will change it and report back on the results.

Comment: I just want to make sure that I get this right. You want me to store the date like this, 2018-05-05 which in php is 'Y-m-d' right?

Comment: Of course you can store it however you want, but meta fields are compared like numbers or like strings. If you store date like you do, then comparing dates makes no sense... Since '10 Oct 2100' < '20 Jan 1990' when you compare them this way.

Comment: Yes. 'Y-m-d' or 'Ymd' formats both will be OK, but first one is nicer for humans.

Comment: I have done that and I am still getting the same results

Comment: If I use WP_CRON, would I still have to loop through all the posts or could I do it witout the loop?

Comment: Oops. I missed your last comments. Hope my answer helps.

Comment: Thank you, it has worked. It has finally returned the correct data. Now to action the data. The issue was the way the date was stored. Once I updated the meta_query it returned correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You must change your date to an ordering like @ Krzysiek Dróżdż said or use [meta_type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/__construct/#parameters) options. I have tested with the string version.

An example of meta_type `$args` is listed below. See also [MySQL time variants](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)

```
/*
Plugin Name: Meta Filter
Plugin URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/304333
*/

// ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=304333

function wpse_304333() {
    echo '<p>wpse_304333</p>';

    $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'my-post-type',
        'meta_key'   => 'my-date-as-string-yyyy-mm-dd',
        'meta_value' => '2018-03-00', // before march 2018
        'meta_compare' => '>',
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $titles = '';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        $titles .= '<br/>' . get_the_title();
    endwhile;
    echo $titles;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'wpse_304333' );
```

uses an SQL containing something like

```
AND ( 
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'my-date-as-string-yyyy-mm-dd'
    AND wp_postmeta.meta_value < '2018-03-00' )
)
```

Or use meta_type like

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'my-post-type',
    'meta_key'   => 'my-date-key',
    'meta_value' => $date_value
    'meta_compare' => '>',
    'meta_type' => 'DATETIME'
);
```

which is SQL converted using CAST. You can run the SQL below to check what values are 'cast' properly.

```
SELECT meta_value, CAST(meta_value AS DATETIME)
  FROM wp_postmeta
 WHERE CAST(meta_value AS DATETIME) IS NOT NULL
```